# How to draw clickable line in PIXI.js using PIXI.Graphics?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pixi.js

I have got the following code:

```
const linksGraphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

const update = () => {
linksGraphics.clear();
linksGraphics.alpha = 1;
if (forceLinkActive) { 
  data.links.forEach(link => {
    let { source, target } = link;
    linksGraphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
    linksGraphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
    linksGraphics.lineTo(target.x, target.y);
  });
  linksGraphics.endFill();
}  }


app.ticker.add( () => update() );
```

Where data.links is an array of edge data {source: number, target: number}. If I understand right, all lines are part of the PIXI.Graphics object. But what I need:

1. every line should have own opacity
2. every line should have an event for mouse over

Any ideas how modify my code?

Thanks.

Comment: As of 5.2.4, it's not possible to interact with a line out of the box: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/6527

I need it as well, would be interested if anyone has a solution

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but can make a suggestion. Lines do not react to mouse/pointer over events in pixijs.

Instead you may want to accompany a transformed rectangle with alpha value 0 and listen mouse/pointer with this rectangle.

For example lets, change the alpha value of the line when mouse/pointer hovers the accompanying rectangle.

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0x283230
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// 1. PRELIMINARY COMPUTATIONS
// Coordinates of the end points of a line
let x0 = 100;
let y0 = 100;
let x1 = 200;
let y1 = 200;
// Find midpoint for translation
let xmid = 0.5*(x0+x1);
let ymid = 0.5*(y0+y1);
// Length of the line
let length = Math.hypot(x0-x1, y0-y1);
// Alignment angle of the line, i.e. angle with the x axis
let angle = Math.atan((y1-y0)/(x1-x0));

// 2. LINE 
line = new PIXI.Graphics();
// Arbitrary line style, say we have a non-white background
line.lineStyle(8,0xffffff,1);
line.moveTo(x0,y0);
line.lineTo(x1,y1);


// 3. ACCOMPANYING RECTANGLE
line.rectangle = new PIXI.Graphics();
line.rectangle.beginFill(0xffffff);
// Since we are going to translate, think of 0,0 is the center point on the rectangle
// Width of the rectangle is selected arbitrarily as 30
const width = 30;
line.rectangle.drawRect(-length/2,-width/2,length,width);
line.rectangle.endFill();
line.rectangle.alpha = 0;
line.rectangle.interactive = true;
line.rectangle.on("pointerover", reactOver);
line.rectangle.on("pointerout", reactOut);
// Apply transformation
line.rectangle.setTransform(xmid, ymid,1,1,angle);

app.stage.addChild(line);
// Add rectangle to the stage too.
app.stage.addChild(line.rectangle);

// Let's change alpha value of the line when user hovers.
function reactOver(){
   line.alpha = 0.5;
}
function reactOut(){
   line.alpha = 1;
}
```

[To the PEN, Hover a line in pixijs](https://codepen.io/yvzt/pen/NWwVbMe)

We can expand this logic to a rectangle for instance. But this time you need two accompanying rectangles (with alpha=0) where one of them is wider and the other is narrower than the unfilled rectangle. For example,

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0x283230
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
const x = 100;
const y = 100;
const width = 150;
const height = 100;
const hoverWidth = 20;

const rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
rect.lineStyle(4, 0xffffff,1);
rect.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
rect.outer = new PIXI.Graphics();
rect.inner = new PIXI.Graphics();
// Fill outer
rect.outer.alpha = 0;
rect.outer.beginFill(0xffffff);
rect.outer.drawRect(x-hoverWidth/2, y-hoverWidth/2, width+hoverWidth, height+hoverWidth);
rect.outer.endFill();
// Fill inner
rect.inner.alpha = 0;
rect.inner.beginFill(0xffffff);
rect.inner.drawRect(x+hoverWidth/2, y+hoverWidth/2, width-hoverWidth, height-hoverWidth);
rect.inner.endFill();
// Add interaction and listeners
rect.outer.interactive = true;
rect.inner.interactive = true;
rect.outer.on("pointerover", pOverOuter);
rect.outer.on("pointerout", pOutOuter);
rect.inner.interaction = true;
rect.inner.on("pointerover", pOverInner);
rect.inner.on("pointerout", pOutInner);
app.stage.addChild(rect);
app.stage.addChild(rect.outer);
app.stage.addChild(rect.inner);


// Listeners
let overOuter = false;
let overInner = false;
function pOverOuter(){
  overOuter = true;
  changeAlpha();
  // rect.alpha = 0.5;
}

function pOutOuter(){
  overOuter = false;
  changeAlpha();
}

function pOverInner(){
  overInner = true;
  changeAlpha();
  // rect.alpha = 1;
}

function pOutInner(){
  overInner = false;
  changeAlpha();
  // rect.alpha = 0.5;
}

function changeAlpha(){
  rect.alpha = (overOuter && !overInner)? 0.5: 1;
}
```

[To the PEN, Hover a rectangle in pixijs](https://codepen.io/yvzt/pen/BamepZg)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a hitArea on a graphic. And with getBounds() you can make a line clickable. After you do that you can also assign pointerEvents to the graphic.

```
const linksGraphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

const update = () => {
  linksGraphics.clear();
  linksGraphics.alpha = 1;

  if (forceLinkActive) { 
    data.links.forEach(link => {
       let { source, target } = link;
       linksGraphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
       linksGraphics.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
       linksGraphics.lineTo(target.x, target.y);

       //A line itself is not clickable
       linksGraphics.hitArea = linksGraphics.getBounds();
    });
    linksGraphics.endFill();
  }  
}


app.ticker.add( () => update() );
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first requirement, try creating separate graphics objects for drawing each line and set alpha for each line.
For your second requirement, You need to set the interactive property of graphics (linksGraphics) object to true like below,

```
linksGraphics.interactive = true;
```

and then attach a function to be executed on mouseover event like below,

```
var mouseOverAction = function () {
       //Some code
};
linksGraphics.on('mouseover', mouseOverAction);
```

Comment: Mouse actions don't work for me only for lines. This example works fine for rectangles and circles and maybe for other objects.